# Deriving from a base class with a static struct

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, linker

I have a number of classes that are all going to share the same information, so I thought I would create a static struct within a base class and then inherit from it for all the derived classes.   But I am running into problems with linking and the symbols are not found.   How do I do this properly?

Here is the struct:

```
struct Settings {
    string Baseurl;
    string Username;
    string Password;
};
```

Here is the base class:

```
class Base {
protected:
    static Settings _settings;
    static curl _http;

    Base();
    ~Base();
};
```

Derived classes:

```
class WebMethod1 : Base {
}

class WebMethod2 : Base {
}
```

I don't necessarily need to set these values on the constructor, but it seems that vs2013 wants me to do so.   But not sure how to go about it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class Base you declare a static `Settings` called `_settings` (which is in the namespace of Base). This *declaration* merely states intent. Now you also have to provide the *definition*:

In a cpp file write this:

```
Settings Base::_settings;
```

Now you have *defined* (given substance to) the symbol `Base::_settings`. You've defined it as a default-constructed instance of Settings.

update:

Similarly, you have *declared* Base::Base() and Base::~Base(). You will need to provide *definitions* of these methods.

An empty constructor would look something like this:

```
Base::Base() {
}
```

The destructor would look something like this:

```
Base::~Base() {
}
```

or

```
Base::~Base() = default;
```

A few observations:

1. Base is a base class, so make the destructor `virtual`.
2. If the base class constructor doesn't do anything, don't declare it. You're giving yourself a maintenance problem for code that does nothing.

Comment: Makes sense, but linker is still missing something when my other project tries to link in the library where WebMethod1 is defined.   I get this error:  `error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00047B) "public: __cdecl Base::Base(void)" (??0Base@@$$FQEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl Test::WebMethod1(void)" (??0Test@@$$FQEAA@XZ) D:\Projects\Test.obj Test`

Comment: The constructor at this time doesn't do anything, but it will down the road.  The problem actually turned out that there was a build order problem and the linker wasn't picking up the right lib.  It seemed to be one step behind my changes.   Thanks for the help!